How I add 'Batch_Size' or Retry point in my LLM?
I am using LlamaIndex with Pandas Dataframe Query Pipe line. While I am using big dataset (infact it has only 500 rows), I am getting only partial output. Seems like LLM limitations. How I mitigate that issue? LlamaIndex suggested me to use Batchsize. But I am new and I am not sure where and how I add that in my LLM.
This is reference to LlamaIndex Pandasquery : https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/examples/pipeline/query_pipeline_pandas/
My LLM and Embeddings code is here:
from llama_index.llms.azure_openai import AzureOpenAI
from llama_index.embeddings.azure_openai import AzureOpenAIEmbedding
from llama_index.core import VectorStoreIndex, SimpleDirectoryReader
import logging
import sys

logging.basicConfig(
    stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO
)  # logging.DEBUG for more verbose output
logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout))


api_key = "xxxx"
azure_endpoint = "xxxx"
api_version = "xxxx"

llm = AzureOpenAI(
    model="gpt-35-turbo",
    deployment_name="gpt-35-turbo",
    api_key=api_key,
    azure_endpoint=azure_endpoint,
    api_version=api_version,
    temperature=0,
)

# You need to deploy your own embedding model as well as your own chat completion model
embed_model = AzureOpenAIEmbedding(
    model="text-embedding-ada-002",
    deployment_name="text-embedding-ada-002",
    api_key=api_key,
    azure_endpoint=azure_endpoint,
    api_version=api_version,
)

from llama_index.core import Settings

Settings.llm = llm
Settings.embed_model = embed_model


import logging
import sys
from IPython.display import Markdown, display

import pandas as pd
from llama_index.core.query_engine import PandasQueryEngine


logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout))

